# Pass ViewModel to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

`MySpecialView` is a complex image control, I would like to reuse it from different views and pass its `ViewModel` as in this example.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="YouBug.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YouBug"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:MySpecialView ViewModel="{Binding MySpecialViewModel}"></local:MySpecialView>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel

```
    public class MainViewModel
{
    public MySpecialViewModel MySpecialViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MySpecialViewModel = new MySpecialViewModel();
        //gets not displayed!
        Task.Run(() => MySpecialViewModel.changeImage(5000, "C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\Capture.PNG"));
    }
}
```

MySpecialView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="YouBug.MySpecialView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YouBug"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
</Grid>
```

MySpecialView.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MySpecialView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(MySpecialViewModel), typeof(MySpecialView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new MySpecialViewModel(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public MySpecialViewModel ViewModel { get { return (MySpecialViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); } set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); } }

    public MySpecialView()
    {
        DataContext = ViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MySpecialViewModel

```
    public class MySpecialViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public BitmapSource imageSource { get; set; }
    public BitmapSource ImageSource { get { return imageSource; }
        set { if (value != imageSource)
            {
                imageSource = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource");
            }
        } }

    public MySpecialViewModel()
    {
        //gets displayed
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\test.jpg"));

        //gets displayed aswell
        Task.Run(() => changeImage(10000, "C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\clickMe.png"));
    }

    public async void changeImage(int sleep, string uri)
    {
        await Task.Delay(sleep);
        BitmapSource source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
        source.Freeze();
        ImageSource = source;
    }

}
```

But whenever I assign `MySpecialViewModel`s Properties from `MainViewModel`, the `RaisePropertyChange` event does not force the `Image` element or other bindings to update from the `MySpecialViewModel`.

What am I doing wrong here? Is this a general wrong approach?

Comment: `DataContext = ViewModel` what ... what are you doing?  Look, you have to treat your UserControls like any other control.  Do you think the TextBox does something like this?  No.  Your ViewModels/Models flow to the TextBox through the DataContext and you bind to properties on the TextBox against what is in its DataContext.  There is none of this `DataContext = ViewModel` or `DataContext = this` jiggery pokery nonsense going on.  Don't.  Please.

Comment: @Will There is nothing wrong with setting `ViewModel` to `DataContext`. The problem is there are two `BitmapSource` properties, when there should only be one. Plus, an instance of the view model is never made. @Milleu Please research your questions more thoroughly next time, all questions in this thread have already been answered elsewhere on SO. If you understand MVVM so little, you should start with an MVVM tutorial and try learning the concepts involved, first.

Comment: The Main reason for my "non-sense" was to get the ViewModel in Code-Behind for some events (not avoidable) - ViewModel { get {return (MySpecialViewModel )DataContext; } } was much simplier, but answers helped a lot thanks! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are too used to "View-First-Approach" (VFA). Your situation is better off using "ViewModel-First-Approach" (VMFA). In VFA, you place your child views from the main View, and each subview is linked to the respective ViewModel via `DataContext`.

In VMFA, your ViewModel holds references of sub-ViewModels. You expose these ViewModel references through property binding, and the View display them via `DataTemplate`.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="YouBug.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YouBug"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MySpecialViewModel}">
            <local:MySpecialViewModel />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ContentControl Content={Binding MySpecialView}" />
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase // Not sure why you didn't subclass ViewModelBase in your question
{
    private MySpecialViewModel _mySpecialViewModel;
    public MySpecialViewModel MySpecialViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _mySpecialViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _mySpecialViewModel)
            {
                _mySpecialViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(); // The property changed method call
            }
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MySpecialViewModel = new MySpecialViewModel();
        //gets not displayed!
        Task.Run(() => MySpecialViewModel.changeImage(5000, "C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\Capture.PNG"));
    }
}
```

`MySpecialView` does not need that `DependencyProperty`, nor set the `DataContext`. The `DataContext` is set automatically by the `DataTemplate` part. Your `MySpecialViewModel` can stay as it is now.

### Edit

I just realized your MainWindow is not doing the `DataContext` correctly either.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not specify viewmodel property in you view, use DataContext.
See the following code.

```
public partial class MySpecialView : UserControl
{

    public MySpecialView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

ViewModel for special:

```
public class MySpecialViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public BitmapSource imageSource { get; set; }
    public BitmapSource ImageSource { get { return imageSource; }
        set { if (value != imageSource)
            {
                imageSource = value;
 RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource");
            }
        } }

    public MySpecialViewModel()
    {
        //gets displayed
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\test.jpg"));

        //gets displayed aswell
        Task.Run(() => changeImage(10000, "C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\clickMe.png"));
    }

    public async void changeImage(int sleep, string uri)
    {
        await Task.Delay(sleep);
        BitmapSource source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
        source.Freeze();
        ImageSource = source;
    }

}
```

In XAML special:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="YouBug.MySpecialView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YouBug"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
    </Grid>
```

For main:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MySpecialViewModel SpecialViewModel
    { 
        get { return _specialViewModel; }
        set
        {
          if (value != _specialViewModel)
          {
             _specialViewModel= value;
             RaisePropertyChanged("SpecialViewModel");
          }
        } 
     }

    private MySpecialViewModel _specialViewModel;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MySpecialViewModel = new MySpecialViewModel();
            //gets not displayed!
            Task.Run(() => MySpecialViewModel.changeImage(5000, "C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\Capture.PNG"));
        }
    }
```

And in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="YouBug.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YouBug"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <MainWindowViewModel/
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <local:MySpecialView DataContext="{Binding Path=SpecialViewModel}"></local:MySpecialView>
</Grid>
```